# Random Music Playback [WinAmp && Cubed]

Tags: 2.2-froyo, music-player

I've noticed this issue on my Sprint Samsung Intercept running 2.2 Froyo (rooted, custom kernel, etc.) I swear I didn't have this issue on Android 2.1, but someone with a Motorola Droid running 2.1 did, as you can see here: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=323590

My issue is I love the WinAmp music player. However, when I pause it and leave the app, it will randomly, unexpectedly begin music playback later (both when I am using the phone, and when it's sitting on the ground next to me.) When I navigate to the app, the controls show that it is paused, and clicking on it once will bring it to the normal state (shows as playing, and it is,) and a second time will pause it again (where it should have been to begin with.) This could be a real issue while I'm in class, etc. and I'm forced not to be able to use WinAmp, which I'd really like to be able to do.

With Cubed, the issue is similar. Instead of having it be random though, it plays when I go back to the app. This leads me to believe that it's playing onResume(), without first checking the state it should be in. I'm guessing WinAmp is staying open in the background somehow and doing the same thing.

My question is, is there any fix?

Comment: Are you using a hands free set or headphones, does that have any buttons on it that you might have knocked?

Comment: I had pretty much the same problem with my Droid: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/why-is-doubletwist-launching-and-playing-when-i-remove-the-headphones Never did find a solution. (Don't listen to music much on the Droid.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to have this problem a lot on my Droid.  I believe it has something to do with the headphones and how some music apps react to you plugging them in/out.

My solution?  I use tasker to make two profiles:

**Not Headset Plugged**

- Music Stop
- Media Volume 0

**Headset Plugged**

- Music Stop
- Media Volume 5

The volume isn't necessary (just so I don't blare loud music into my ears when I put in my ear buds OR sets it 0 if I unplug my headphones and it somehow is still playing).  So in other words every time I plug in or out my headphones, it stops all music.  Since I've done this, I've had no more problems.

Comment: I was wondering about headphones. Cubed actually seems to be working since I last reset my phone, so I'll see if it works. Otherwise this seems like the best solution, thanks. Though even when I stop music, unplug earbuds, it will start playing again even before I put earbuds back in, which is the issue. But if I use Tasker to turn Media Volume to 0, and 10, that should work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This seems ideal if you have Tasker, but I'd love a free, non-widget solution - I'm still experiencing this bug daily.

Answer (score 0):

There was a notable bug in earlier versions of Android ( I can vouch that it exists in 2.1) that music would play out of the loudspeakers at random times or just after you'd unplugged your earphones.

I used [Headset Blocker Widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/headset-blocker/com.idunnolol.headsetblocker), after someone recommended it and have never encountered the above-mentioned scenario of random playing or music playing once I've unplugged my earphones.