# Default Music Player randomly playing while headphones are plugged in

Tags: music-player, bugs, headphone-jack

This is *INCREDIBLY* annoying. While listening to music, the headphone will somehow trigger an unplug event (the connection is loose and very bad apparently). The default player will start to play, and sometimes it will just keep playing and pausing rapidly. Sometimes, Pandora will also constantly play and pause music. This is so frustrating it makes me just want to smash my phone to pieces for the junk it is. What can be done? I have used [this answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/random-music-playback-winamp-cubed/4962#4962), but it doesn't fix the problem *while* playing music.

The only way I can hope to currently listen to music on my phone is to make sure the connection from the headphone (any headphone) isn't disturbed. My phone basically doesn't play music well at all any more which means no more Pandora/internet radio.

**What can/should I do?** I am using a Droid X with the latest update 2.3.3. I believe this problem has been happening for a while. I bought the phone in October and it worked without this kind of problem for about 2-4 months.

Am I the only one with this bug?

Comment: I understand your frustration, but please make this less of a rant and more of a question.

Comment: Can you please say what kin of phone

Comment: Im having the same problem, i use the music player while running, it does the same thing, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

How long have you had your phone? One common cause of intermittent headphone connections like this can just be that after carrying your phone around in your pocket for months, it has picked up "pocket fluff" in the headphone socket. At first this just squashes down out of the way when your headphones are plugged in, but after a while so much builds up that it stops the headphones plugging in fully and making a secure connection.

Removing this fluff can be as simple as just pulling it out [with a straightened paper clip](http://www.andybarratt.co.uk/iphone-headphone-buttons-fixed) (be careful when you stick it in there). This is what I found by in my headphone socket a little while ago with a paper clip.

[image]

There are also some [slightly more complicated](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayScKPuZPuM) ways to [give the socket a good clean](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Clean-a-18-3.5mm-Headphone-Jack/).

This fluff problem is far more common with smart phones, than with stand-alone MP3 players or old-fashioned walkman-type devices, as you'd commonly leave the headphones permanently plugged into those older single-purpose devices, whereas people usually leave the headphone socket empty on general purpose smart phones most of the time, and slip them in and out of fluff and lint filled (and generating) trouser pockets.

Comment: Interesting, wouldn't have thought of this. +1

Comment: @BryanDenny neither did I until an iPhone using friend mentioned to me a few weeks ago that he'd had this problem and was amazed at how much compacted fluff had built up in there, of course after hearing that I had to see how much was in my phone! It fixed my problem with Listen podcasts randomly cutting out as I walked around.

Comment: @ GAThawn you are the MAN. there was a GIANT piece of lint in there. I had to manipulate it a few times before finding it but like you said, I could see into there and notice it wasn't all metal/shiny for the male plug to conduct to. I'll accept if this fixes the problem.

Comment: @GAThawn unfortunately the issue still remains. The problem is that the "default music player" keeps turning on while I'm already listening to other music and if the device is moved enough.. It seems to be less crazy though when it happens.